# Call class function before calling super in javascript class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to extend Request object in JavaScript. My use case is that I want to include some more methods and modify URL according to `httpMethod`.

I have tried like the following:

```
class ServiceRequest extends Request {
  constructor(config) {
    const url = config && config.url;
    const method = config && config.method;
    const body = config && (JSON.stringify(config.body) || {});
    const headers = (config && config.headers) || new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    });
    if (url && method) {
      const apiUrl = this.buildAPIPath(url, method);
    }
    super(apiUrl, {method,body,headers});
  }
  buildAPIPath (url, httpmethod) {// all the url modifications return modify url;}
}
```

Now it is giving error without super I can not call this. My problem here is that the url is read only, so I cannot call super first. If I call super first then I cannot reassign url.

Some suggestions on how I can make it work?

Comment: It gets pretty messy when inheritance kicks in. Have you tried using object/function composition?

Comment: No. can you elaborate more object/function composition.

Comment: Might be unrelated but still possible typo fix `const body = config && JSON.stringify(config.body || {});`

Comment: Well, if you are not too deep into dev stage and used "inheritance" in your code, then it is not too far to try functional programming in JS.  You can get started with [this for example.](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/why-composition-is-harder-with-classes-c3e627dcd0aa) I get that this is not the solution to your problem, but its another perspective to look upon.

Comment: Thanks @KarenGrigoryan

Comment: Constructor code isn't valid because apiUrl is scoped and will result in type error.

Comment: @RoliAgrawal you are welcome to upvote my answer below if you found it useful, I pointed there to apiUrl scope issue as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to extend `Request` object in JavaScript.

There's absolutely no reason to do that - you're not overwriting any of its methods. Just write a normal function that returns a normal `Request`:

```
function buildAPIPath (url, httpmethod) {
  // all the url modifications
  return /* modified url */;
}
export function ServiceRequest(config) {
  const url = config && config.url;
  const method = config && config.method;
  const body = config && JSON.stringify(config.body || {});
  const headers = (config && config.headers) || new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  });
  const apiUrl = buildAPIPath(url, method);
  return new Request(apiUrl, {method,body,headers});
}
```

> It is giving error I can not call this class function before calling super

Yes. Before the `super` call, no instance exists, so you cannot call any methods on it. There's really no way around this. But your `buildAPIPath` method does not *use* an instance anyway, so it should not be a method at all. You would use a plain function declaration outside of the `class`, or a static method (which you could call with `new.target.buildAPIPath(…)` or `ServiceRequest.buildAPIPath(…)`).

Comment: Why in your solution you also use `JSON.stringify(config.body)` but leave default `{}` as an object? Why did you decide to skip `if (url && method) {`  logic branch? and where is the explanation of that change?

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan I just kept the `const body` line from the OPs code without even looking at what it does. Skipping the `if (url && method)` check is necessary for `apiUrl` to be placed in the correct scope where it  is available to the returned `new Request` call. I don't know what it should do when the condition is not met, an exception is probably in order.

Comment: 1. Anyways it's a potential error in the answer, doesn't matter how you perceived it and reacted to it. 2. You didn't mention that in your answer, that you deliberately decided to remove the `if` branch for that. 3. Furthermore, there is  no need to delete the `if` branch, since you can still have the `if` branch and have the reference correctly withdrawn into a higher scope (you can have a look at my answer for example). By deleting the if branch you are unnecessarily affecting the deliberate branching, who's evident purpose was to check for `method` existence and act differently.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan I didn't mention it explicitly because it's not relevant for the question, which is about super calls and instance methods. I just fixed the scope error in the easiest way (and if `url`/`method` don't exist `buildAPIPath` will throw). Using `url` for the default is another choice.

Comment: 1. it's not relevant until you reintroduce it in your answer, and it's hard to tell whether it's intentional or typo, unless explicitly explained. 2. In OP's code initially `apiUrl` is going to error out in either scenario. even if you have `url`, `method` it will still error out since `const` is visible only in local block scope. 3. So it's not another choice, it's just fixing the OP's code without altering semantics. A real another choice might be just lifting the variable to upper scope without defaults.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan You will have to ask the OP whether it was intentional and what erroring behaviour `apiUrl` should have, not me - but either way, it's not the topic of this question.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan i am more concerned the pattern for calling super . rest logic will  change according to need. currently my only concern is calling class method before super since my parent class is readonly.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your time . I think yes i can make it as function will serve the purpose . accepting as its useful for solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`this` class instance cannot be accessed before `super` because ES6 classes were designed this way, and there's no workaround. If there's a need to do that, ES6 class should be desugared to regular constructor function that doesn't have this limitation.

This is not the case, because `buildAPIPath` doesn't involve class instance, so it can be static method:

```
class ServiceRequest extends Request {
  static buildAPIPath(url, httpmethod) {
    /* ... */   
  }

  constructor(config) {
    /* ... */
    if (url && method) {
      apiUrl = new.target.buildAPIPath(url, method);
    }
    super(apiUrl, {method,body,headers});
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get your "common recipe". Why not just call `buildAPIPath` directly? Also if you call (either) method on `ServiceRequest`, no override will ever be used.

Comment: This can prevent ServiceRequest from being extended further if there's a need to override buildAPIPath in child class. That's the only downside of static buildAPIPath method in my opinion, I just addressed it. I had numerous cases (primarily third-party libs) where I had to copy and paste a class because a developer didn't have a thought that somebody can benefit from extending it.

Comment: I still don't get it. Did you design the `ServiceRequest` class in your snippet so that it can be extended, and if yes how? Also what exactly is the difference between `_buildAPIPath` and `buildAPIPath`?

Comment: `class FooServiceRequest extends ServiceRequest { static buildAPIPath(...) { ... } }`. Wouldn't be possible with `ServiceRequest.buildAPIPath(...)` called directly in constructor.  I'm quite sure I encountered this solution in other people's code, so I didn't invent it.

Comment: Just noticed that new.target has gained full support in both Babel and TS, so it will be a better choice here.

Comment: But it's wrong. Calling `new FooServiceRequest` will *not* use the overridden method, regardless whether you have the underscored method (`ServiceRequest._buildAPIPath(…)`) in the constructor or not (`ServiceRequest.buildAPIPath(…)`) . Using `new.target` is the (only) key to the solution.

Comment: Definitely. Mixed it up with my another case, thanks for noticing. As for new.target transpilation, a class that extends a built-in would cause issues any way.

Answer (score 0):

Since Request API is mostly read-only, the better approach may be to create a class wrapper around Request object, instead of extending it, something like this:

```js
class ServiceRequest {
  constructor(config) {
    const url = config && config.url;
    const method = config && config.method;
    const body = config && JSON.stringify(config.body || {}); // changed this as {} should also be stringified
    const headers = (config && config.headers) || new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    });
    let apiUrl = url; // apiUrl should be outside if statement, to not error out
    if (url && method) {
      apiUrl = this.buildAPIPath(url, method);
    }
    this.request = new Request(apiUrl, {method,body,headers});
  }
  buildAPIPath (url, httpmethod) {
    // all the url modifications return modify url;
  }
}
```

And later use it with `fetch` like this:

```js
const {request} = new ServiceRequest({/*opts*/})
fetch(request);
```

Comment: What is a "class wrapper"? What did you change in the code? Why are you not doing anything with the `new Request`? Why are you still using `this` without a `super` call in an `extend`ed class?

Comment: @Bergi it was a typo, I forgot to remove the `extends` part. Thanks for observation.

Comment: OK, that resolves the last of my questions, but not the other ones.

Comment: @Bergi updated with more explanations and another typo fix, thanks for valuable input.